# Boiler plate code for webstorm angular js

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Is there any boiler plate code available for `angularJs` that I can use with `webstorm` for speedy development. Bascially i am looking for code snippets to quickly create controllers, services, directives etc.

I think `sublime` provides that feature, but not sure if we can do that in `webstorm` or not.

Comment: This question is not suitable for s.o.  Try asking it at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Settings | Editor | Live Templates | AngularJS. See  http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-code-constructs-by-live-templates.html for more information about live templates